# C++ winsock problem reconnecting socket after it has been closed

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I am building an application that uses Windows sockets for communication. The `Client` class handles the connection and spawns a thread that should periodically check if the connection is alive and if it's not, it should try to reconnect.

```
bool Client::Connect() {
    fSocket = WSASocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, nullptr, NULL, NULL);
    if (WSAConnect(fSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &fAddress, sizeof(fAddress), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr) != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void Client::StartConnectionAndKeepAlive() {
    auto threadFunction = [this]() {
        while (true) {
            if (!this->fConnected) {
                this->CloseConnection();
                this->Connect();
                this->Send("Hello from thread!\n");
            }
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    };
    fThread = new thread(threadFunction);
}

bool Client::Send(const string& data) {
    auto nBytesSent = send(fSocket, data.c_str(), int(data.size()), NULL);
    cout << "nBytesSent: " << nBytesSent << " for data: " << data << endl;
    if (nBytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        fConnected = false;
        return false;
    }
    fConnected = true;
    return true;
}
```

After instantiating `Client`, `Client::StartConnectionAndKeepAlive()` is called. If the connection is not possible, the value of `send` will be equal to `SOCKET_ERROR` as expected.

However my problem is when the server closes the connection (I am currently using `netcat` and close the connection just by `ctrl+C`). After closing the connection the return value of `send` is the same as when the connection is alive. This causes the flag `fConnected` to stay true and therefor the connection won't be restablished even if I launch `netcat` again.

This is the first time I am working with sockets and windows so I am surely mising something but I couldn't find a solution online. All similar question responses state that the return value of `send` should be `SOCKET_ERROR` if there is no connection (if I understood them correctly) but I found it's not the case.

I am aware that I should probably use `std::mutex` in my class since I am using it from multiple threads but found that adding it doesn't make my problem disappear, I removed them to keep the code simpler.

Any feedback to my implementation is also welcome! Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/685981/1047662, I guess you could also use `WSAEventSelect` or `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` to wait for a close event happening on the socket.

Comment: Thanks @Cyclonecode, I checked that answer before but for example the information stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/686002/11776908 is incompatible with my experience unless I am missing something. I will take a closer look thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the problem is related to `netcat`. I implemented a simple `socket` server using `node.js` and in fact the return value of `send` is `SOCKET_ERROR` after the connection is closed. However this does not happens when you close the `netcat` connection which was started with the `nc -lvnp` flags.

Comment: A socket can't detect in a timely manner when the connection is lost *abnormally*, such as when killing the peer process. It can take several minutes for the OS to timeout internally and invalidate the connection locally. Until then, `send()` will happily keep buffering data normally. You have to turn on TCP keelaives, or use timeouts in your own code, to handle this.