# Check Socket File Descriptor is Available?

Tags: c, select, sockets

If I got a file descriptor (socket fd), how to check this fd is avaiable for read/write?
In my situation, the client has connected to server and we know the fd.
However, the server will disconnect the socket, are there any clues to check it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `fcntl()` to check for read/write settings on the fd:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int    r;

r = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
if (r == -1)
        /* Error */
if (r & O_RDONLY)
    /* Read Only */
else if (r & O_WRONLY)
    /* Write Only */
else if (r & O_RDWR)
    /* Read/Write */
```

But this is a separate issue from when the socket is no longer connected. If you are already using `select()` or `poll()` then you're almost there. `poll()` will return status nicely if you specify `POLLERR` in `events` and check for it in `revents`.

If you're doing normal blocking I/O then just handle the read/write errors as they come in and recover gracefully.

Comment: Doesn't this just check the file lock?  That seems like a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select()` or `poll()` for this.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, this question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722240/instantly-detect-client-disconnection-from-server-socket)

In general, socket disconnect is asynchronous and needs to be polled for in some manner.  An async read on the socket will typically return if it's closed as well, giving you a chance to pick up on the status change quicker.  Winsock (Windows) has the ability to register to receive notification of a disconnect (but again, this may not happen for a long time after the other side "goes away", unless you use some type of 'keepalive' (SO_KEEPALIVE, which by default may not notice for hours, or an application-level heartbeat).

Answer (score 0):

I found the recv can check. when socket fd is bad, some errno is set.

```
ret = recv(socket_fd, buffer, bufferSize, MSG_PEEK); 
if(EPIPE == errno){
// something wrong
}
```

Comment: EPIPE does not mean the socket FD is bad. It means the connection is broken. Not the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could call select(). If the server has disconnected, I believe you'll eventually get an error code returned... If not, you can use select() to tell whether you're network stack is ready to send more data (or receive it).

Comment: I think `select` may trigger the *exceptfds* argument if the remote end disconnected, but not return any error.