# c++ file descriptor (sockets) isopen()?

Tags: c++, sockets

In C++, is there a way to check if a file descriptor is still open, long after it was initially opened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [fcntl with the F_GETFL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893055/check-socket-file-descriptor-is-avaiable/893133#893133) to get if the fd is valid or not.

Comment: If the file descriptor was closed, fcntl will fail.  (So it doesn't matter whether you use F_GETFL or any other command.)

Answer (score 2):

`fstat` is the most portable way I can think of.

If you tell us what platform, we may be able to suggest something better for your particular situation.