# Is it safe to parse a /proc/ file?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, procfs

I want to parse `/proc/net/tcp/`, but is it safe?

How should I open and read files from `/proc/` and not be afraid, that some other process (or the OS itself) will be changing it in the same time?

Comment: +1. That's a _damn_ good question. I only wish I had the answer, but I look forward to finding out since I've done that sort of thing quite a bit before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure just _reading_ it will give you a list of connections, plus the UID that owns each one, as they were when you _opened_ it. I can't find that documented, however, so making this a comment for now.

Comment: Simple answer is obviously yes, as it is not a file - reading it should always be safe. Answers may not be consistent subsequent times you read it, but it will be safe.

Comment: This is why you should use sysctl instead. (its also fewer syscalls)

Comment: @GoodPerson - how can this `sysctl` help me parse a `/proc/net/tcp/` file, for example?

Comment: @KirilKirov - you would look up which sysctl you want and not use /proc at all

Answer (score 123, accepted):

**In general, no.** (So most of the answers here are wrong.) It *might* be safe, depending on what property you want. But it's easy to end up with bugs in your code if you assume too much about the consistency of a file in `/proc`. For example, see [this bug which came from assuming that `/proc/mounts` was a consistent snapshot](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=593516).

For example:

- **`/proc/uptime`** is **totally atomic**, as someone mentioned in another answer -- but *only since Linux 2.6.30*, which is less than two years old.  So even this tiny, trivial file was subject to a race condition until then, and still is in most enterprise kernels.  See [`fs/proc/uptime.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/fs/proc/uptime.c) for the current source, or [the commit that made it atomic](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=a9caa3de249a6c43bc9c6aec87881f09276677e3).  On a pre-2.6.30 kernel, you can `open` the file, `read` a bit of it, then if you later come back and `read` again, the piece you get will be inconsistent with the first piece. (I just demonstrated this -- try it yourself for fun.)
- **`/proc/mounts`** is **atomic within a single `read` system call.** So if you `read` the whole file all at once, you get a single consistent snapshot of the mount points on the system. However, if you use several `read` system calls -- and if the file is big, this is exactly what will happen if you use normal I/O libraries and don't pay special attention to this issue -- you will be subject to a race condition. Not only will you not get a consistent snapshot, but mount points which were present before you started and never stopped being present might go missing in what you see. To see that it's atomic for one `read()`, look at [`m_start()` in `fs/namespace.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/fs/namespace.c#L889) and see it grab a semaphore that guards the list of mountpoints, which it keeps until `m_stop()`, which is called when the `read()` is done.  To see what can go wrong, see [this bug from last year](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=593516) (same one I linked above) in otherwise high-quality software that blithely read `/proc/mounts`.
- **`/proc/net/tcp`**, which is the one you're actually asking about, is even less consistent than that.  It's **atomic only within each row of the table**.  To see this, look at [`listening_get_next()` in `net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1964) and `established_get_next()` just below in the same file, and see the locks they take out on each entry in turn.  I don't have repro code handy to demonstrate the lack of consistency from row to row, but there are no locks there (or anything else) that would make it consistent.  Which makes sense if you think about it -- networking is often a super-busy part of the system, so it's not worth the overhead to present a consistent view in this diagnostic tool.

The other piece that keeps `/proc/net/tcp` atomic within each row is the buffering in `seq_read()`, which you can read [in `fs/seq_file.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/fs/seq_file.c#L132). This ensures that once you `read()` part of one row, the text of the whole row is kept in a buffer so that the next `read()` will get the rest of that row before starting a new one. The same mechanism is used in `/proc/mounts` to keep each row atomic even if you do multiple `read()` calls, and it's also the mechanism that `/proc/uptime` in newer kernels uses to stay atomic. That mechanism does *not* buffer the whole file, because the kernel is cautious about memory use.

Most files in `/proc` will be at least as consistent as `/proc/net/tcp`, with each row a consistent picture of one entry in whatever information they're providing, because most of them use the same `seq_file` abstraction.  As the `/proc/uptime` example illustrates, though, some files were still being migrated to use `seq_file` as recently as 2009; I bet there are still some that use older mechanisms and don't have even that level of atomicity. These caveats are rarely documented. For a given file, your only guarantee is to read the source.

In the case of `/proc/net/tcp`, you can read it and parse each line without fear. But if you try to draw any conclusions from multiple lines at once -- beware, other processes and the kernel *are* changing it while you read it, and you are probably creating a bug.

Comment: what about readdir atomicity? like reading /proc/self/fd ? is it safe?

Comment: Not that it answers the question but to add about how to check uptime you can use *`clock_gettime(2)`* with *`CLOCK_MONOTONIC`* (though maybe there is a technicality I'm unaware of here but I personally have only seen it with since time of boot). For Linux you also have the option of *`sysinfo(2)`*.

Comment: /proc/mounts cannot be consistently read with a single huge read, as internal seq_file.c buffer is one page size by default, and once filled, the read ends. So the biggest chunk of /proc/mounts that can be read consistently is as much entires as will fit in 4096 bytes, except for some very unusual circumstances (first line has over 4096 bytes).

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/2/openat will it solves the race condition problem?

Comment: strace -e verbose=all cat /proc/net/tcp

Answer (score 45):

Although the files in `/proc` appear as regular files in userspace, they are not really files but rather entities that support the standard file operations from userspace (`open`, `read`, `close`). **Note that this is quite different than having an ordinary file on disk that is being changed by the kernel.**

All the kernel does is print its internal state into its own memory using a `sprintf`-like function, and that memory is copied into userspace whenever you issue a `read(2)` system call.

The kernel handles these calls in an entirely different way than for regular files, which could mean that the entire snapshot of the data you will read could be ready at the time you `open(2)` it, while the kernel makes sure that concurrent calls are consistent and atomic. I haven't read that anywhere, but it doesn't really make sense to be otherwise.

My advice is to take a look at the implementation of a proc file in your particular Unix flavour. This is really an implementation issue (as is the format and the contents of the output) that is not governed by a standard.

The simplest example would be the implementation of the [`uptime`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/uptime.c) proc file in Linux. Note how the entire buffer is produced in the callback function supplied to `single_open`.

Comment: @Ignacio: I'm just pointing the OP in this direction because I was left with the impression that he thinks that `proc` files are ordinary files opened for writing by the kernel.

Comment: Your advice to look at the implementation of the specific file is good. Unfortunately the guess that it's all snapshotted at `open()` is wrong for many files, and in particular for `/proc/net/tcp`, which the OP is concerned with. This makes sense if you think about the cost of providing those semantics -- you'd have to do something like lock the internal data structures that record all those TCP connections, which on a busy system is a disaster even if you only hold it long enough to scan through and format the data to a buffer. See my answer for details on what actually happens.

Answer (score 17):

/proc is a virtual file system : in fact, it just gives a convenient view of the kernel internals. It's definitely safe to read it (that's why it's here) but it's risky on the long term, as the internal of these virtual files may evolve with newer version of kernel.

**EDIT**

More information available in [proc documentation in Linux kernel doc](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt), chapter 1.4 Networking
I can't find if the information how the information evolve over time. I thought it was frozen on open, but can't have a definite answer.

**EDIT2**

According to [Sco doc](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/man/html.4/proc.4.html) (not linux, but I'm pretty sure all flavours of *nix behave like that)

> Although process state and
>   consequently the contents of /proc
>   files can change from instant to
>   instant, a single read(2) of a /proc
>   file is guaranteed to return a
>   ``sane'' representation of state, that
>   is, the read will be an atomic
>   snapshot of the state of the process.
>   No such guarantee applies to
>   successive reads applied to a /proc
>   file for a running process. In
>   addition, atomicity is specifically
>   not guaranteed for any I/O applied to
>   the as (address-space) file; the
>   contents of any process's address
>   space might be concurrently modified
>   by an LWP of that process or any other
>   process in the system.

Comment: "I think" ? It would be nice to have a definitive answer :)

Comment: Given the implementation of /proc in the kernel, this also holds true for linux. If you read a procfs file in a single read call, it's consistent - of course assuming the proc file you read has been implemented correctly kernelside.

Comment: I don't think you could come up with a worse possible source of information than SCO, and trying to treat `proc` as if it has similar behavior between different kernels (or even assuming it exists -- it doesn't have to in a Unix system) is going to get you a world of hurt.

Comment: @Nicholas : well, couldn't find some definitive answer in the kernel doc, feel free to point it if you know it.

Comment: Interesting that the SCO docs say that.  Unfortunately it's not always true in Linux, and in particular it is not true for `/proc/net/tcp`, which is the OP's main concern.  Rather, only each individual row in the output is atomic.  See my answer for details.

Comment: **not linux, but I'm pretty sure all flavours of *nix behave like that** Whether or not this is directly relevant I do not know but SCO isn't exactly a decent organisation (i.e. untrustworthy, etc.)... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCO/Linux_controversies comes to mind. But fact remains they seem to have many false beliefs and ideas...

Answer (score 15):

The procfs API in the Linux kernel provides an interface to make sure that reads return consistent data. Read the comments in [`__proc_file_read`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.38/fs/proc/generic.c#L41). Item 1) in the big comment block explains this interface.

That being said, it is of course up to the implementation of a specific proc file to use this interface correctly to make sure its returned data is consistent. So, to answer your question: no, the kernel does not guarantee consistency of the proc files during a read but it provides the means for the implementations of those files to provide consistency.

Comment: Unfortunately, many files in `/proc` do not in fact provide consistency.  See my answer for details.

Comment: Also, `__proc_file_read()` is deprecated in favor of `seq_file`.  See the rather exasperated-sounding comment (by Linus) just above the long block comment.

Answer (score 6):

I have the source for Linux 2.6.27.8 handy since I'm doing driver development at the moment on an embedded ARM target.

The file ...`linux-2.6.27.8-lpc32xx/net/ipv4/raw.c` at line 934 contains, for example

```
    seq_printf(seq, "%4d: %08X:%04X %08X:%04X"
            " %02X %08X:%08X %02X:%08lX %08X %5d %8d %lu %d %p %d\n",
            i, src, srcp, dest, destp, sp->sk_state,
            atomic_read(&sp->sk_wmem_alloc),
            atomic_read(&sp->sk_rmem_alloc),
            0, 0L, 0, sock_i_uid(sp), 0, sock_i_ino(sp),
            atomic_read(&sp->sk_refcnt), sp, atomic_read(&sp->sk_drops));
```

which outputs

```
[wally@zenetfedora ~]$ cat /proc/net/tcp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
   0: 017AA8C0:0035 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 15160 1 f552de00 299
   1: 00000000:C775 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 13237 1 f552ca00 299
...
```

in function `raw_sock_seq_show()` which is part of a hierarchy of *procfs* handling functions.  The text is not generated until a `read()` request is made of the `/proc/net/tcp` file, a reasonable mechanism since *procfs* reads are surely much less common than updating the information.

Some drivers (such as mine) implement the proc_read function with a single `sprintf()`.  The extra complication in the core drivers implementation is to handle potentially very long output which may not fit in the intermediate, kernel-space buffer during a single read.

I tested that with a program using a 64K read buffer but it results in a kernel space buffer of 3072 bytes in my system for proc_read to return data.  Multiple calls with advancing pointers are needed to get more than that much text returned.  I don't know what the right way to make the returned data consistent when more than one i/o is needed.  Certainly each entry in `/proc/net/tcp` is self-consistent.  There is some likelihood that lines side-by-side are snapshot at different times.

Comment: Really sorry, I didn't get it much. So, do you mean, that if I use `ifstream`, it will be unsafe, but if I use `read` it will be safe? Or `ifstream` uses internally `read`? And what do you suggest?

Comment: @Kiril:  Sorry for the confusion.  This is an explanation of how the data for `/proc/net/tcp` is formatted and is completely independent of how anyone reads it.

Comment: Yep! And your guess is correct that different lines (in `/proc/net/tcp`) do not come from the same snapshot. See my answer for some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Short of unknown bugs, there are no race conditions in `/proc` that would lead to reading corrupted data or a mix of old and new data. In this sense, it's safe. However there's still the race condition that much of the data you read from `/proc` is potentially-outdated as soon as it's generated, and even moreso by the time you get to reading/processing it. For instance processes can die at any time and a new process can be assigned the same pid; the only process ids you can ever use without race conditions are your own child processes'. Same goes for network information (open ports, etc.) and really most of the information in `/proc`. I would consider it bad and dangerous practice to rely on any data in `/proc` being accurate, except data about your own process and potentially its child processes. Of course it may still be useful to present other information from `/proc` to the user/admin for informative/logging/etc. purposes.

Comment: I'm doing this to get and **use** some information **for my own process** (for my PID, using `getpid()`). So, it gotta be safe.

Comment: Yes, I would consider that completely safe.

Comment: I don't agree that child processes would be any better behaved than any other process.  As far as the `/proc` interface is concerned, they all have the same weaknesses and strengths.  Anyway, the OP asks about device driver related information, not processes.

Comment: If pid `N` is your child process, you can ensure that pid `N` still refers to that same (possibly terminated) process until you call a `wait`-family function on it. This ensures that there are no races.

Comment: What's with the flood of -1's and no explanation?

Comment: @R.. Simple. People tend to be cowards in that way; this goes everywhere in the world. It's criticising rather than constructive criticism. It's sad but it's reality and whatever your answer says - or whatever any answer says whether completely wrong, mostly wrong, correct utterly or anything else - I feel empathise with you. It's extremely frustrating and it doesn't allow improving answers; not only improving but you could for example learn more. Just under 7 years old but I wanted to give you support there.

Answer (score 2):

When you read from a /proc file, the kernel is calling a function which has been registered in advance to be the "read" function for that proc file.  See the `__proc_file_read` function in fs/proc/generic.c .

Therefore, the safety of the proc read is only as safe as the function the kernel calls to satisfy the read request.  If that function properly locks all data it touches and returns to you in a buffer, then it is completely safe to read using that function.  Since proc files like the one used for satisfying read requests to /proc/net/tcp have been around for a while and have undergone scrupulous review, they are about as safe as you could ask for.  In fact, many common Linux utilities rely on reading from the proc filesystem and formatting the output in a different way.  (Off the top of my head, I think 'ps' and 'netstat' do this).

As always, you don't have to take my word for it; you can look at the source to calm your fears.  The following documentation from proc_net_tcp.txt tells you where the "read" functions for /proc/net/tcp live, so you can look at the actual code that is run when you read from that proc file and verify for yourself that there are no locking hazards.

> This document describes the interfaces
>   /proc/net/tcp and /proc/net/tcp6.
>   Note that these interfaces are
>   deprecated in favor of tcp_diag.
>          These /proc interfaces provide information about currently active TCP
>   connections, and are implemented by
>   tcp4_seq_show() in net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c
>   and tcp6_seq_show() in
>   net/ipv6/tcp_ipv6.c, respectively.