# Android Marshmallow permission model on OS 4.0 READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission always not granted

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a problem when running my app on Android OS 4.0 and requesting `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission with:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ctx, requestedPermissions, requestCode);
```

I always get on the callback

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) { 

grantResults != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Checking the permission with `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission` is always returning `permissionDenied`.

It works well on OS 6.0 by requesting the permission with system dialog.
Android OS 4.x excepted the 4.0 the permission is always granted.
OS 4.0 the other permissions (Camera,Calendar,Contact,Phone) are behaving well except the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` causing this issue.

Maybe an OS issue?

Comment: This is weird. Can you try using normal method of permission that is <Activity>.requestPermission( requestedPermissions, requestCode);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129716/how-does-storage-access-change-on-android-6

Comment: @dex The problem is that activity related methods for permissions are only accessible on API 23

Comment: @Skirx : Yes you need to set targetSDK = 23 and compileSDK = 23 to use them, if you not setting these then you will not able to support Android M any how

Comment: @dex The problem here is that I'am setting android:minSdkVersion="14" and android:targetSdkVersion="23". and as you can see on the question below getting permissionDenied on 4.0.3.
if i set android:minSdkVersion="23" and android:targetSdkVersion="23" it works only on OS 6.0 and the behaviour is normal, no problems. Here the problem is that the checkSelfPermission must return Granted on OS 4.0.3 instead of Denied. CompatLibrary issue I think

Comment: @skirix I am not asking to change the minSDK. I am saying change the compileSDK and TargetSDK and use activity method. if you are using gradle android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'.... } <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

Comment: @abforce Thank you for the edit and the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[What `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` does](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.java) is:

- call through to the real `requestPermissions()` if you are on Android 6.0+, or
- use `PackageManager` to see if you hold the requested permissions on older versions of Android

The problem with `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is that it was added in API Level 16 (Android 4.1). You cannot hold it on older versions of Android than that, for the simple reason that it did not exist.

Either:

- Set your `minSdkVersion` to 16, or
- Put your own logic in to handle this case, recognizing that `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is irrelevant prior to API Level 16

Comment: A simple workaround is to ask for the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission instead, which is API 4. In M, `WRITE` and `READ` live in the same permission group, so asking for the former will grant access to the latter as well. The only downside is that versions prior to 4.1 will see that a new permission is required, if you were previously only asking for `READ`.

Comment: @dextor: That assumes that Android will always ask the user for rights at the level of the permission group, not the level of the permission. I would not make that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this issue when dealing with `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` on Android 8.0. My solution unfortunately depends on the exception handling, but it does not require dealing with the API level the permission is supported from. You can check if permission exists on current API level with this method:

```
private boolean permissionExistsOnCurrentApiLevel(String permission) {
    try {
        getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(permission, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

With this method you can implement you own version of `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` where all non-existing permission are automatically considered to be granted:

```
private int myCheckSelfPermission(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String permission) {
    if(!permissionExistsOnCurrentApiLevel(permission)) {
        return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
}
```