# Accessing getExternalStorageDirectory

Tags: android

Using some pretty simple android code I am trying to access a folder according to the following logic:

```
public void try_to_navigate_local_dir(){
    Environment e = new Environment();
    ArrayList<String> filesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String sd_card = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/subdir_x";
    File file = new File( sd_card ) ;
    File list[] = file.listFiles();
    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++) {
        filesList.add( list[i].getName() );
    }
}
```

Where `subdir_x` is created by another application on my phone.

I can view in those folders using file manager, yet my code returns null when I try to `file.listFiles()`.

How may I access these files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 3):

Prior to Marshmallow, follow @Cory Charlton's answer. However his answer for Android Marshmallow (6.0) won't work.

Actually as of Android 6.0 (API level 23), we don't have the following permission anymore.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For more information, please this question:

- [Android Marshmallow permission model on OS 4.0 READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission always not granted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482474/android-marshmallow-permission-model-on-os-4-0-read-external-storage-permission)

By the way, `Environment e = new Environment();` is useless, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `AndroidManifest.xml` has the appropriate permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The next problem might be your filename. I use the following in one of my applications and it works (note the trailing slash and lack of leading slash):

```
directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Subdirectory/")
final File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

The next problem might be the path `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is giving you. Newer devices have a partition on the internal storage that emulates an sd card and `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` can return this rather than the real sd card.