# How do I call Poll() with this SOCKET?

Tags: c++, c, windows, sockets, networking

```
SOCKET server = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);  
bind(server, 7.7.7.7, sizeof(7.7.7.7) );  
listen(server, 0);


server.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead);
```

> error C2228: left of '.Poll' must have
>   class/struct/union type

The IP is not the same but the 3 functions work correctly creating a socket that the server can listen to and send data, to the client.

I would like to poll the client, [using this example but in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722240/instantly-detect-client-disconnection-from-server-socket).

Which object or structure can I use here with Poll()?

Comment: Those three functions really work?! I want that compiler of yours.

Comment: It's not out yet but if you wire me $1,000 I can get you a copy. Please send me your bank routing number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read this [Tutorial](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).
What you are doing doesn't look close to correct.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, `Socket` is a class type, and has a [`Poll()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.poll.aspx).

In C++, `SOCKET` is a handle type, not a class type, so there is no `Poll()` method available. You need to use the [`select()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141.aspx).