# Tcpip connection established via ADB gets disconnected as soon as the USB is unplugged

Tags: android, usb, adb, tcpserver, usb-debugging

This had been working fine for me all the while, now all of a sudden I find this change in behaviour with no change in android or my wondows(I haven't updated either)

This is how I establish wireless connection over tcpip

```
adb -d tcpip 5571
adb connect 192.168.68.110:5571
```

Now after this `adb devices` when usb is kep plugged outputs:

> List of devices attached

> ZY223SVNKZ      device

> 192.168.68.110:5571     device

when I uplug the usb it used to output:

> List of devices attached

> 192.168.68.110:5571     device

But all of a sudden it's now outputing blank after unplugging:

> List of devices attached

I have read [Listening for an Ethernet Cable Unplugging Event for a TCP Server Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298824/listening-for-an-ethernet-cable-unplugging-event-for-a-tcp-server-application)
But it doesnt answer my question. I have established connection via `adb` so looking for an adb based solution as well. I have also gone through

- [TCP Server disconnect/cable unplugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410946/tcp-server-disconnect-cable-unplugged)
- [Listening for an Ethernet Cable Unplugging Event for a TCP Server Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298824/listening-for-an-ethernet-cable-unplugging-event-for-a-tcp-server-application)
- [Instantly detect client disconnection from server socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722240/instantly-detect-client-disconnection-from-server-socket)
- [Detecting TCP Client Disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283375/detecting-tcp-client-disconnect)

None of these answers my question. So please don't blindly close it refereing any of these. I need a `adb` based solution or some sorts of android settings which can solve it.

Comment: I know that answer is given. But, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318581/android-wifi-adb-keeps-disconnecting-in-android-studio visit this link. This might help you. I did face the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me upgrading adb version from 39 to 41 fixed the issue.
I agree it may not be a fullproof solution, but it worked for me.

Other solution which others mentioned on similar threads were

1. migrating from usab3.0 to usb2.0 solved for someone but it didnt solve for me .
2. changing usb mode from file transfer to charge only solved for someone but it didnt solve for me.

You can try those too if upgrading adb version doesnt work for you.