# Writing to network stream after closing of listener

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

When using tcpclient for writing to socket as in example below

Server:

```
tcpListener.Start(PendingClientCount);
tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(OnAcceptCompleted, null);
////and more code
```

Client:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 50000));
var clientStream = client.GetStream();
if (clientStream.CanWrite)
{
  clientStream.Write(preparedPackage, 0, preparedPackage.Length);
}
clientStream.Close();
client.Close();
```

It turns out then after closing of server by calling tcpListener.Close() and Dispose() I can write bytes to network stream, and they go to "nowhere". After passing certain time interval (approx. 2 minutes) attempt ti network stream fails (at last).

Is there any possibility to detect that nobody listens to socket on opposite side when trying to write to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instantly detect client disconnection from server socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722240/instantly-detect-client-disconnection-from-server-socket)

Comment: Are you calling `Close` on the accepted socket at the server end?

Comment: 2Nick: yes, Close() was called

Comment: Not just on the `TcpListener`? I mean the socket which you will have been provided with when you accepted the connection.

Comment: Lowest level is TcpClient (result of calling AcceptClient), and it was closed along with TcpListener

Comment: I've tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/722265/187130 and it works