# How do you detect a bluetooth hardware disconnect using the 32feet libraries?

Tags: bluetooth, disconnect, 32feet

Our hardware is behaving normally.  Paired, sending receiving using a data socket, no issues with initialization or performance.

Rarely, the bluetooth hardware will disconnect.  We don't have the ability to poll the connection and so we require a property or method that can be checked to see if the bluetooth connection has dropped.

Is there an event, method, or property node which is designed to detect the bluetooth connection dropping?

Comment: Question also asked on Github:
https://github.com/barometz/flint/issues/2

Comment: can the .connected property be used, or the RSSI?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the method of detecting a disconnect for other sockets (TcpSocket for example) works for 32feet, see [Instantly detect client disconnection from server socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722240/instantly-detect-client-disconnection-from-server-socket)